# Volley Not making request on latest version of Android

Tags: java, android, android-volley, android-9.0-pie

I noticed my app wasn't working on Pixel 3. I went into android studio and emulated a few devices and noticed it is not working on any Android Pie (API 28) devices, but works fine on any other. I put a few logs throughout my code, and it seemed that I was not getting a response within my Volley usage. The app itself loads, but does not display any data, and I receive an error

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

My code is

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseManagement db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = new DatabaseManagement(this);
        grabData();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.hellapunk.hellapunk.feature.Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, 3000);
    }

    public void grabData() {
        //Log.i("Made it", "You made it this far");
        String url = "http://hellapunk.com/listallshows.php?id=2018";
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray showInfo = new JSONArray(response);
                    Log.i("Something", "response");
                    for (int i = 0; i < showInfo.length(); ++i) {
                        JSONObject showInfo1 = showInfo.getJSONObject(i);

                        if ((db.checkShow(showInfo1.getString("show_summary"),
                                showInfo1.getString("show_date"))) > 0) {
                            Log.i("Results", "Show already exists");
                        } else {
                            db.insertShows(showInfo1.getString("show_summary"),
                                    showInfo1.getString("venue_name"),
                                    showInfo1.getString("show_date"),
                                    showInfo1.getString("shows_img"),
                                    showInfo1.getString("venue_address"),
                                    showInfo1.getString("city_name"),
                                    showInfo1.getString("city_region"));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("Error", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("TAG", ""+error);
            }
        });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(sr);

    }
}
```

I grab the data during my splash screen and store it into a local database. Then it is called from the db on the next Activity. Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: may be your are getting network security error. any error you are getting?

Comment: Why do you think this error has anything to do with Volley?

Comment: Any Errors in logcat?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is because starting with Android P, any network traffic between your app and insecure destinations must be explicitly whitelisted. See [Protecting users with TLS by default in Android P](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/protecting-users-with-tls-by-default-in.html).

In your code, you're making a request to:

```
http://hellapunk.com/listallshows.php?id=2018
```

The `http://` shows that the site is not secure. If you dig deeper into your LogCat you'll likely find a message such as:

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to hellapunk.com not permitted
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:177)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to hellapunk.com not permitted
    at com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler$CleartextURLFilter.checkURLPermitted(HttpHandler.java:115)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:458)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:538)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:99)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:131)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120) 
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)
```

Attempting it myself, it doesn't appear that the site supports `https` connections, so in order to reach this particular server from your application, you would need to whitelist the `hellapunk.com` domain manually.

In your resources directory, define an XML document for your network security configuration (e.g. `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`):

**network_security_config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">hellapunk.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Then, in your `AndroidManifest.xml` for your application, in the `<application>` tag, add the attribute:

```
<application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

You should then be allowed to make insecure requests to any domain specified within that file.

Comment: Thanks so much! I wasn't aware of the TLS by default, and much rather have it that way anyways. I just set up certbot on the server to fix that. I appreciate the info!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Ahh...saved my day!

Comment: Nice answer with explaination. Working fine

Comment: What happened if this is ip address only?

Answer (score 6):

It is working well in **Pie Api 28**

**network_security_config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

In the android manifest Application Tag, add these lines.

```
 android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use usesCleartextTraffic attribute under the application element in the android manifest. The default value in Android P is “false”.

```
<application
     android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

</application>
```

but it requires minSdkVersion 23 or higher.

Comment: nice trick!!! it is working for xampp localhost also, because it is http. much thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this issue i use https and its working very well now