# Image Uploading issue in Android Pie from gallery to server

Tags: java, android

When uploading an image from gallery to Rest API works fine on old Android devices. The image is uploaded perfectly to server. But when I upload it using new Android Pie device, image is not uploaded.

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Uri SelectedImage = data.getData();
            filePath = (String) getRealPathFromUri(getActivity(),data.getData());
            photoFile = new File(filePath);
            img_image.setImageURI(SelectedImage);

        }
    }
```

Comment: share your upload code or any error you get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Volley Not making request on latest version of Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176034/volley-not-making-request-on-latest-version-of-android)

Answer (score 0):

For Android PIE you need to declare a network-permission.

1. Go to your res folder, and search for a xml folder (if you don't have it then create it).
2. Create a file i usually named it: **network_security.xml** but you can call it however you like.
3. Inside the file .xml add your domain.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">IP ADDRESS IF LOCAL</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">8.8.8.8</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">myserverhosted.com</domain>
    </domain-config> </network-security-config>
```

4. Open your **AndroidManifest** and add this.

```html
<application
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

This should help with your problem.

Comment: I have add this things before that has not a issue but when i am upload image from gallery it sets in mobile but when it sends to server then image is not uploaded to server. I have used Multiparts