# Volley not compatible with SDK 28

Tags: android, android-volley

I upload the sdk version from 27 to 28 and the app is not working properly.

I debugged the app and the problem is Android Studio does not execute this and jumps to the return.

What I do here is connect to an http address and retrieve it's data to a list.

```
 JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(ConfigRed.INF_USERS_URL,
            response -> {

                //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                parseData(response);
            },
            error -> {
         //       Toast.makeText(ActividadPrincipal.this, "No se puede descargar usuarios, Obteniendo usuarios locales", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                DatabaseHelper db;
                db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                listUsuarios = db.getMuestreadoresConMuestrasCargadas();

                if (listUsuarios.size() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActividadPrincipal.this, "No hay registros previos de usuarios. Conectate al laboratorio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    no_internet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    adapter.setUsuarios(listUsuarios);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                db.closeDB();
            });

    //Returning the request
    return jsonArrayRequest;
```

I tried this solution but i still retrieving an empty list

[Volley Not making request on latest version of Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176034/volley-not-making-request-on-latest-version-of-android)

I think is because I'm trying to access an http site despite https but I don't know what to do because with the sdk 27 the app runs with no problems but I need using sdk because of google play politics.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: I'm not sure I undersood. Is the URL you're trying to reach in `http` or `https` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can found the solution in this topic

[How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

The problem was because the use of http, which is by default blocked by Android 9

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this into your manifest in Application tag. then it will work smoothly.

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"